# Raspberry Pi does not show up in workgroup, samba is running, user added

Tags: samba

I have followed the [following guide](https://www.howtogeek.com/139433/how-to-turn-a-raspberry-pi-into-a-low-power-network-storage-device/) to setting up a network accessible external HDD on my pi. I installed both samba and samba-common-bin. I entered the formatted the external drive and mounted it just as in the guide.

I edited the samba config file to include details for the shared folder as follows:

```
[Share]
comment = Share Folder
path = /media/USBHDD1/shares
valid users = @users
force group = users
create mask = 0660
directory mask = 0771
read only = no
umask=022
```

I have added a samba user and given it a password. I've restarted the samba server. Yet the pi still does not show up in my Windows WORKGROUP. Any ideas?

Could it be that I also use this pi as a private VPN server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I could connect to it using it's IP address instead. This allowed me to simply set that up as the network drive.